# Homework help Prove that $n + (−1)^n \cdot 2$ is not a monotone sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

**I don't want anyone to do the proof**.

My problem is, isn't this a monotonic sequence?

When I take increasing values of n the sequence grows larger. $(-1)^n \cdot 2$ alternates between $2$ and $-2$. Even if the question is supposed to say $(-1)^{n^2}$ then it alternates between $1$ and $-1$. By adding the $n$, $n + (−1)^n \cdot 2$, doesn't this become monotonic? Since for increasing values of $n$ subtracting one or two is not going to stop it from increasing.

Thus it is monotonically increasing? 
I don't know if this is a trick question or if I'm just misunderstanding something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A sequence $(a_n)_n$ is called **monotonic increasing** if $a_{n+1}\geq a_n$ for all $n$.

Your sequence is somehow increasing, that is right. But by definition it is not monotonic increasing, since $a_2=2+(-1)^2\cdot 2=4>1=3+(-1)^3\cdot 2=a_3$.

So the alternating part destroys the monotonicity property.